# Remove sub-string if it is not what we want?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a substring that I need to look for and if it is not what we want, it has to be removed.

It is a bit different than just finding the substring and removing it because the substring is dynamic. Because i can easily do something like this:

```
var updatedString = originalString.replace("Joined-44", "");
```

Example:

I have a string that loks like this. This is the content of a DIV element:

```
Hello world, Are you OK? Blah blah bla Joined-1 Joined-44 Some more texts goes here... Joined-2 Joined-5...
```

Now I need to keep everything as it is BUT remove every `Joined-x` words apart from the Joined-1 & Joined-2.

Could someone please advice on this?

Comment: `str.replace(/Joined\-[3-9][0-9]+/, "")` maybe?

Comment: @JonasW. That would miss `Joined-10` through `Joined-29`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could keep the ones with `1` and `2` while replacing all others.

It takes a regular expression

```
/joined-(\d+)/gi
```

which looks for the string `joined-` literately and for a group of one or more digits. The flags are `g` for global, which means search for more than one time and `i` for case insensitive.

The replacement function checks if the digit is equal to one or two, then it returns the whole found pattern, or if not, an empty string.

```js
var string = 'Hello world, Are you OK? Blah blah bla Joined-1 Joined-44 Some more texts goes here... Joined-2 Joined-5...'

console.log(string.replace(/joined-(\d+)/gi, (p, d) => d == 1 || d == 2 ? p : ''));
```

Comment: It will be nice if you can add an explanation what it does too.

Comment: It will help the new comers a lot. Thank you.